# SortedDict: Sort by value in python

Tags: python, dictionary, sorteddictionary

[SortedDict](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sorteddict.html) is a class that inherits from dictionary and keeps elements sorted by key all the time. We can also specify for it to sort by some function of the key as follows.

```
def func(x):
    return -x

sd = SortedDict(func)
```

However, I would like to have it sort by values of the dictionary.
For example:

```
d = {0:[34, 67, 3],1:[12, 4, 9],2:[25, 3, 1]}
```

I want this to be sorted by the first element of each array, so that I have a sorted dict as follows:

```
sd = {1:[12, 4, 9],2:[25, 3, 1],0:[34, 67, 3]}
```

Is there a way for me to do it? If I do the following:

```
def func(x):
   return d[x][0]
```

this is not a permanant solution, because, if I update my sorted dictionary:

`sd.update({4:[6,5,9]})`

I get a key error from the original dictionary.

I need a way for the function to access the value of the key in sd itself. Would this be possible?

Comment: Is there any particular reason for keeping the array sorted?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value - you could maintain an OrderedDict if you want instead of just building and returning one whenever needed, but I believe you would have to rebuild it on every insert.